# Changing String to Floating Point Number in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a list made up of strings in a dictionary to float variables.

Here is the code I was given:

```
data = {'year':[1990, 2000, 2010], 'gdp':['8.95', '12.56', '14.78']}
```

The end result is supposed to look like this:

```
data = {'year':[1990, 2000, 2010], 'gdp':[8.95, 12.56, 14.78]}
```

Thank you in advance for any hints or help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order that we may better answer your question, please post a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, edit your question to include the code you have written for your solution attempt, as well as any errors/output from it. Understand that the answerers on this site are *volunteers*; while we will be glad to answer *specific* questions you may have, this is **not** a site where code is written for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
data = {'year':[1990, 2000, 2010], 'gdp':['8.95', '12.56', '14.78']}
data['gdp'] = [float(string) for string in data['gdp']]
```

Comment: Also consider an explicit loop that just replaces each list element without creating an entirely new list: `for i, x in enumerate(data['gdp']): data['gdp'][i] = float(x)`.